# What are the metal parts at the end of this spindle called?

Tags: stairs

What is the name of the metal parts at the ends of this spindle?
Is there a generic name for this style of "whatever their name is"?
Trying to buy them separately but I can't find them and I think I am not using the right key words
[image]

Comment: What keywords have you tried?

Comment: "wood and metal stair balusters" with only one valid return from google ( https://prestigemetal.com/en/balusters-accessories/141-gt-010.html)

Comment: Try out "metal spindle cap/post/knuckle". It's not exact but it's getting warmer I think.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. _Why_ do you need just the metal parts? Is it a repair job and the metal has failed? Do you want to install new balusters and this is the style you like (or already have) and are looking to get just the ends and supply your own wood in the middle? Something else entirely?

Comment: You'd probably get a more conclusive answer from visiting a metal fabrication shop and just asking someone there.

Comment: @FreeMan I need them in white oak and they come in read or maple only

Comment: If you have identified a vendor that supplies them in the "wrong" wood, you might ask _them_ if they'll custom make them with white oak, or if they'll sell you just the ends so you can supply your own wood.

Comment: see my comments to Jay613's answer, that is the plan

Comment: there is a slight problem the balusters Rona sells are 1 1/16" as per the specs https://www.rona.ca/en/product/colonial-elegance-urban-balusters-maple-and-stainless-steel-36-in-l-smn10036-08856120  I am not sure if that is the size including the metal piece or not but if that is the size of the wood then I will need to buy 2" thick white oak boars which will increase the price

Comment: I wouldn't buy boars, as I'm convinced having wild pigs running about the house won't help the situation. However, most every hardwood supplier out there would be happy to sell you 5/4 white oak that could be planed down to 1-1/16". Most would be happy to do the finishing work for you (for a charge, of course), should you not have (access to) the tools to do so. There is absolutely _zero_ reason to go to 8/4 wood to get that extra 1/16" inch.

Comment: step by step the price for these damn spindles is going up to match the price for the entire stairs

Answer (score 1):

They are called "Baluster shoes".   They are shoes regardless of top or bottom and often come in matching pairs.   It may be hard to find your specific ones but that's not the question.

Credit to OP MiniMe for taking us one step closer to this with "spindle shoe".

Comment: They do not sell them like that. The cost retail cost is pretty high https://www.rona.ca/en/product/colonial-elegance-urban-balusters-maple-and-stainless-steel-36-in-l-smn10036-08856120

Comment: Actually I should look at the problem the other way around, I need to see the cost of getting the wood to make the wood part of the spindle white oak. If that is cheap (I doubt because it is white oak) then I can order the above linked item from Rona and replace the wood with white oak that I can cut myself to size

Comment: Just for the record that hardware (at least the bottom part) has a name (as per some flooring pros) : spindle shoe hardware

Comment: @MiniMe wow .... answer modified!